# "Maybe" she reviewed the vocabulary so that she was able to pass the exam - do I need to change anything?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

**Example 1**

> She reviewed the vocabulary so that she was able to pass the exam.

**Example 2**

> **Maybe** she reviewed the vocabulary so that she was able to pass the exam.

Example 2 has "Maybe" in it.

Do I need to change anything in the Example 2?

Does Example 2 mean that she definitely passed the exam, or does it mean she might have passed it?

**Example 3**

> She received a pretty good grade because she asked questions in classes.

**Example 4**

> **Maybe** she received a pretty good grade because she asked questions in classes.

Example 4 has "Maybe" in it.

Do I need to change anything in the Example 4?

Does Example 4 mean that the questions-asking is a truth, something that happened?

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing a statement with 'maybe' indicates that the speaker is only guessing that it is true.

Lacking context, Example 4 could mean *either* "I know she received a good grade, and this may be the reason" *or* "I know she asked a lot of questions in class, and it may have resulted in her receiving a good grade."